# github-like svn checkout from git

Tags: git, svn, github, integration

GitHub provide an svn interface to git, explained here:
https://github.com/blog/966-improved-subversion-client-support

Is there a similar solution I can deploy on my self-hosted repositories? Is it open source?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SubGit](http://subgit.com).

One can install SubGit into Subversion repository and use both Subversion and Git. Note that since [version 2.0](http://subgit.com/eap) SubGit is able to synchronize SVN and Git repositories that reside on different hosts.

SubGit is a commercial tool; it's free for open source, academic and small projects. SubGit 2.0 is free as long as it's in EAP stage.

Disclaimer: I'm one of SubGit developers.